# Which host do I need to fill in the database connection?

Tags: database

So I have made a local Drupal site and now I'm moving it to my webhost. In the database connection array:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'drupaldb',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'secret',
  'host' => 'localhost',
);
```

So I filled in all my credentials (driver, database, username,...) but what do I need to fill in after 'host'? Can I just leave it 'localhost' or do I need to fill in the host of my webhosting?

Comment: `localhost` is just fine. It's not some remote host, it's your local machine. It could be translated to "this machine". It's for internal communication.

Comment: But I'm putting the website online, so not only on my local machine anymore. Is localhost still fine then or should I fill in the server name of the webhosting?

Comment: The settings file should reflect the database credentials needed. Some strategies have it checking ENV settings to determine what server it is on, or including different settings files. Using localhost only works if MySQL resides on the same server and allows it to be accessed via `localhost` name. Really, for this you should consult your web host and Drupal docs on settings.php.

Comment: localhost is a special name for the IP address 127.0.0.1, a reserved address for the same machine as the connection is coming from. So wherever the web server is hosted, localhost is the host system. It only refers to your local machine when you are running code on it.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong actually, in regards to at least MySQL, `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` mean different things.

Answer (score 3):

It will depend on your hosting setup and where the DB is located. The `host` value can be:

- A reachable hostname where the PHP code is running (e.g. `localhost` for your local server)
- An IP address (e.g. `127.0.0.1`, the ip address normally used for `localhost`),
- A [fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) (e.g. `my-data-base-host.example.com`)

Consult your hosting provider on retrieving your DB host connection credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give like below for the remote server of drupal8.

```
 $databases['default']['default'] = array (
  'database' => '',
  'username' => '',
  'password' => '',
  'prefix' => '',
  'host' => '',
  'port' => '',
  'namespace' => 'Drupal\\Core\\Database\\Driver\\mysql',
  'driver' => 'mysql',
);
```

You have to give host is webhost.like (wcs-xxxxx).

Answer (score -2):

In the host, you need to add your host IP Address like:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'drupaldb',
  'username' => 'username',
  'password' => 'secret',
  'host' => '111.111.111.111',
);
```

Comment: What is the wrong with my answer?

Comment: The problem with your answer is that you do not indicate *when* this is the correct solution. Hint: rarely.

Comment: Its a common sens. Every Drupal Developer know where we need to add this functionality.Its a first step of Drupal installation.